# Position modal relative element background IONIC

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

It is possible to locate the modal relative to the elements that are in the background, for example if there is an element above that the modal appears above, if the element is in the middle the modal is positioned in the middle or in the place where the element is .

I tried to solve it through media queries but it is very limited to the device for iPhone the range of device is smaller but for android it is more complex, I need it to be exact and not vary according to the device

```
// IOS
@media screen and (max-height: 720px) {
  ::ng-deep .ios .modal-custom {
    top: -7.6 rem;
  }
}

// APK
@media screen and (max-height: 720px) {
  ::ng-deep .md .modal-custom {
    top: -3 rem;
  }
}
```

[image: Images]
[image: Image B]

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to locate the modal relative to the elements that are in the background, for example if there is an element above that the modal appears above, if the element is in the middle the modal is positioned in the middle or in the place where the element is

For that, you can use `position relative` on the background element and `position absolute` on the modal.

```css
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sixing: border-box;
}

.parent{
position: relative;
border: 1px solid red;
width:10rem;
height: 10rem;

}

.child{
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid blue;
/* For centering the child relative to it's parent */
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<h5 class="child">Hello I'm Modal</h5>
</div>
```